# PHP select onchange not working

Tags: php, jquery

So i am creating `<select id="VersionDropdown" onchange="change(this)"></select>` inside of a php file that is then pulled into another php document via `include` tags. The problem that i am having is that `onchange` is never fired off. I have tried using jQuery.change() as well with no success.

I am using jQuery 1.9.1

PHP:

```
<?php
    // Build the dropdown menu based on files on the server

    $dropdown = '<select id="VersionDropdown" onchange="change(this)">';
    $path = './myPath/';
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'SQL Files');

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $root) {
        if($root->isDot()) continue;
        $path2 = $path . $root . '/';
        $MajorVersion = $root->getFilename();
        $MajorVersion = str_replace('v', 'Version ', $MajorVersion);
        if(fnmatch('Version 3.1', $MajorVersion)){ $MajorVersion = str_replace('Version', 'Analog Version', $MajorVersion); }
        //$versions[$MajorVersion] = array();
        $dropdown .= '<optgroup label="' .$MajorVersion. '">';

        foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path2) as $folder) {
            if($folder->isDot()) continue;

            $item = $folder->getFilename();
            //$versions[$MajorVersion][$item] = array();

            if ($handle = opendir($path2 . $item)) {
                while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                    if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
                        if(fnmatch("*.txt", $file)) {
                            $fileNew = str_replace('.txt', '', $file);
                            $versions[$MajorVersion][$item]['Version'] = $fileNew;
                            $dropdown .= '<option value="' .str_replace('Web', '', $item). '">' .$fileNew. '</option>';
                        }else{
                            $versions[$MajorVersion][$item][str_replace('.exe', '', $file)] = $file;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            closedir($handle); 
        }
    }
    $dropdown .= '</optgroup>';
    //print_r($versions);
    $dropdown .= '</select>';

    echo $dropdown;
?>
```

HTML/PHP

```
<html>
<title>Test Script</title>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

 function change(version){
    alert(version);
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include './php/version_dropdown.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

version_download.php output:

```
<select id="VersionDropdown" onchange="change(this)">
    <optgroup label="Version 5.5">
        <option value="55249">5.5.24.9</option>
        <option value="55225">5.5.22.5</option>
        <option value="55205">5.5.20.5</option>
        <option value="55183">5.5.18.3</option>
        <option value="55163">5.5.16.3</option>
        <option value="55141">5.5.14.1</option>
        <option value="55122">5.5.12.2</option>
        <option value="55106">5.5.10.6</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 5.0">
        <option value="50016">5.0.0.16</option>
        <option value="50018">5.0.0.18</option>
        <option value="50022">5.0.0.22</option>
        <option value="50024">5.0.0.24</option>
        <option value="50284">5.0.28.4</option>
        <option value="50304">5.0.30.4</option>
        <option value="50321">5.0.32.1</option>
        <option value="50343">5.0.34.3</option>
        <option value="50403">5.0.40.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 4.3">
        <option value="43062">4.3.0.62</option>
        <option value="43064">4.3.0.64</option>
        <option value="43066">4.3.0.66</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 4.2">
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Analog Version 3.1">
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: since php is running server side, it is not clear that this could ever work unless you show more code. How do you call the php code on the server when the selection changes?

Comment: Could you post some `HTML/PHP` code ? We can't guess the answer..

Comment: `change` Function must be defined after `select` element!Please Add all code.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I have tried $( document ).ready(function() {}); as well as .live() and .bind()

Comment: Does your console come up with any errors? Is JS accidentally disabled in your browser? Can you post the actual HTML output of `version_dropdown.php`?

Comment: I get NO errors in the console. JS is not disabled

Comment: SOOO, this seems to work in FF and IE11 but not chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 $("#VersionDropdown").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "something") {
              //do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: _I have tried using jQuery.change() as well with no success._ probably addresses this

Comment: I have tried $( document ).ready(function() {}); as well as .live() and .bind()

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Edited):

```
$("#VersionDropdown>optgroup>option").on('click', function(event) {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

When you insert a element, after the document charged, you have to use the `.on()` or `.live()` function to make it work.

[More information @ jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: How about `$(document).on('change',"#VersionDropdown", function(){...` you tried that method?

Comment: Try creating the select in the HTML and populating the options with php and jQuery.

Comment: Yes i just tried that and its still not working. arg

Comment: Just edited the jquery. Try it. When you click the option inside the optgruoup, it should alert the text of the option.

Comment: Still nothing happening.. Am i going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to be trying to accomplish this?

Comment: If you are using firefox, you can use firebug to see what happens when you try to fire the event. Use it and tell us what does it say, please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47897/discussion-between-aerojun-and-user1784477)

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an object to the function `onchange="change(this)"`

Change function to:

```
function change(version){
    alert(version.value);
}
```

**Or** change the onchange to

```
onchange="change(this.value)"
```

jQuery not required for the above.

**NOTE** only **one** of the changes above should be made. If you make both you'll be errors

Answer (score 0):

I inserted the output of your php code into the html source that you showed, giving me something that *almost* worked. All I then had to do was to write `alert(version.value);` instead of `alert(version);`, and I was in business. I cannot understand why that does not work for you - please confirm that this works for you, or compare with the source code that you actually get from the server:

```
<html>
<title>Test Script</title>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>

 function change(version){
    alert(version.value);  // <<<<<<<< this line was changed >>>>>>>>>>>
}

$( document ).ready(function() {

}); 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- <<<<<<<<<<<<<< inserted php generated code here as plain text >>>>>>>>>>>> -->
<select id="VersionDropdown" onchange="change(this)">
    <optgroup label="Version 5.5">
        <option value="55249">5.5.24.9</option>
        <option value="55225">5.5.22.5</option>
        <option value="55205">5.5.20.5</option>
        <option value="55183">5.5.18.3</option>
        <option value="55163">5.5.16.3</option>
        <option value="55141">5.5.14.1</option>
        <option value="55122">5.5.12.2</option>
        <option value="55106">5.5.10.6</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 5.0">
        <option value="50016">5.0.0.16</option>
        <option value="50018">5.0.0.18</option>
        <option value="50022">5.0.0.22</option>
        <option value="50024">5.0.0.24</option>
        <option value="50284">5.0.28.4</option>
        <option value="50304">5.0.30.4</option>
        <option value="50321">5.0.32.1</option>
        <option value="50343">5.0.34.3</option>
        <option value="50403">5.0.40.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 4.3">
        <option value="43062">4.3.0.62</option>
        <option value="43064">4.3.0.64</option>
        <option value="43066">4.3.0.66</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Version 4.2">
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Analog Version 3.1">
    </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Just one other observation (which I *assume* to be a typo; but maybe it's the source of your problem). You are `#include`ing `version_dropdown.php`, but you call the file whose contents you are showing `version_download.php`. Typo? Or source of your problem... I have to believe it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally. For whatever reason CHROME was not firing the onchange event!. I restarted chrome and it all of a sudden started working. LAME.

I have had random issues like this in the past where it seems like Chrome suddenly starts caching JS..  /facepalm